# Obtain a string from 1 line string using grep, egrep, or sed with regular expression

Tags: regex, macos, sed, terminal, grep

I have one line string like

```
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x480 [SAR 32:27 DAR 16:9], 2286 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
```

I know that I can obtain " 2286 kb/s" by using cut command.

```
foo='Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x480 [SAR 32:27 DAR 16:9], 2286 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)'
echo $foo | cut -d ',' -f 4
```

But if the field number of " 2286 kb/s" differs, I can't use cut command.  Moreover the unit might be changed like " 16 mb/s".

I think I need to use grep, egrep, or sed with regular expression to obtain the string. But since I'm not familiar with regular expression, I have no idea to how to use them.  Please help me

Comment: what will be constant in it?i mean  will it be always between the 3rd and 4th commas?

Comment: It might not be constant.  This is part of ffmpeg's output.  So if ffmpeg change the spec, I'm not sure where it will be appear...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `grep`:

```
grep -oE '[0-9]+ [km]b/s' <<< "$foo"
```

or `sed`:

```
sed 's|.* \([0-9]* [km]b/s\).*|\1|' <<< "$foo"
```

Comment: If you don't have `-E` you could use `grep -o '[0-9]\{1,\} [km]b/s'`

Comment: Ahhh, I didn't know about `grep -o`. Nice. I thought I'd have to split on the commas.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I can get aimed string with your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of using grep:

```
echo $foo | tr ',' '\n' | grep -e /s$
```

This just looks for anything ending in /s (so mb/s, kb/s gb/s, whatever) on everything between two commas (we swapped commas for newlines with `tr`)

Here is a demonstration of it in action:

```
➜  ~  foo='Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x480 [SAR 32:27 DAR 16:9], 2286 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)'
➜  ~  echo $foo | tr ',' '\n' | grep -e /s$
 2286 kb/s
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use awk like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=", "}/[km]b\/s/' <<<"$foo"
```

`RS` is the record separator, which means every comma separated value will be treated as a separate record. This will print the record when it contains a `k` or `m` followed by `b/s`.

Comment: Nice, I never really learnt awk, it always remained in the "to learn" pile, seems powerful.

Comment: @MikeH-R I'd say `grep` is better suited to this task, I just thought that `awk` deserved a mention as well!